# Unchecked cast: 'java.lang.Object[]' to 'T[]'

Tags: java, generics

I have the following method:

```
public static <T> T[] toArray(Iterable<? extends T> iterable) {
  return (T[]) StreamSupport.stream(iterable.spliterator(), false).toArray();
}
```

My IDE tells me that there is an unchecked cast.
In general, I understand the error message, but I cannot understand why the cast should be checked, because iterable has the same type I use for casting. Can someone please explain this to me?

Comment: Hey! Why are you doing `<? extends T>` instead of just `<T>`?

Comment: Doesn't it make the whole thing even more future-proof?

Comment: No, why would it be "future-proof"? Do you know what `? extends T` does? What happens if you call this method with for `Animal[] as = toArray(some Iterable<Dog>)` or `Dog[] as = toArray(some Iterable<Animal>)` or `Dog[] as = toArray(some Iterable<Dog>)`? Which of them work, why and is that desired?

Comment: There is no "future proof" here. What this does is, it allows someone to do `Animal[] animals = toArray(dogs)`, where `dogs` is, for example a `List<Dog>`. Which can make sense, However, it is not needed because arrays are covariant. So if you leave it as `T` you get back an `Dog[]`, which can be assigned to an `Animal[]` as well because it is covariant. So the wildcard `? extends T` is unecessary in this case.

Comment: I know what you're getting at. I've been looking for other implementations and guava uses it too: [link](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot/api/docs/src-html/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#line.279). What is the difference there?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with it, especially if you want to have more control over the `T`, it is just not really needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> but I cannot understand why the cast should be checked

A checked cast is something that results in a `checkcast` bytecode instruction. For example:

```
String s = (String) someObject;
```

In the case of generics, a `checkcast` instruction can't be inserted, because there is no known type at that point in the code: the type checked by a `checkcast` is statically written into the bytecode; but your method has to work for *all* types. As such, no `checkcast` can be added here.

A warning is the compiler's way of saying "I can't be sure, but something looks a bit fishy here". And, indeed, there is something fishy, but the problem just doesn't occur in this code.

Let's say you call this method something like so:

```
Integer[] ints = toArray(iterableOfInts);
```

There would actually be a checked cast inserted *at the call site* (inserted by the compiler):

```
Integer[] ints = (Integer[]) toArray(iterableOfInts);
```

This will fail at runtime because `Object[]` can't be cast to `Integer[]`. But the failure occurs *here*, rather than in the `toArray` method.

The correct approach to fix this would be to provide something to create the `T[]`:

```
public static <T> T[] toArray(Iterable<? extends T> iterable, IntFunction<T[]> arraySupplier) {
  return StreamSupport.stream(iterable.spliterator(), false).toArray(arraySupplier);
}
```

`Iterable<? extends T>` is an appropriate parameter type, because it lets you create an array of a supertype:

```
Integer[] integers = toArray(iterableOfInts, Integer[]::new);
Object[] objects = toArray(iterableOfInts, Object[]::new);
```